# global variable for path

Tags: uri

In my project I want to provide path of some files from root directory. Path has repeated 4 to 5 time in one module so I am thinking that put one global variable and access that variable in same module?

I have try `(dirname(__FILE__).'\sound\new'); realpath; drupal_realpath ; pathinfo;` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) and [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) to make the variable global.

> - **Set the variable**
>
>   - variable_set('MYMODULE_PATH', base_path() . drupal_get_path('module','YOUR_MODULE_NAME'));
> - **Get the variable**
>
>   - variable_get('MYMODULE_PATH');

Also you can assign multiple values the variable, if you dont want to create multiple variables

```
  variable_set('MYMODULE_PATHS', 
    array( 
      'm1' => base_path() . drupal_get_path('module','YOUR_MODULE_NAME'),
      'm2' => base_path() . drupal_get_path('module','YOUR_MODULE_NAME'),
      ...
    )
  );
  $values = variable_get('MYMODULE_PATHS');
  //Read as $values['m1'], $values['m2'] ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path using drupal default function **drupal_get_path()**;

It return path to any module or theme from root of installation.

If i want to access path of any module e.g. **mymodule**

Then i just need to use,

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module','mymodule');   //path to module directory
```

If i want to access path of my theme e.g. **mytheme**

```
$path =  drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme');   //path to theme directory
```

Now you can make the path variable global..

Comment: Thakns its working with this...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your global variables with multiple ways: for ex: in settings.php file - `$conf['some_name'] = 'some_value'`, or with [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) and [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) (these functions store variable in db instead of defining them as global), or with builtin `$GLOBALS` array, etc..

But as Raj10 mentioned above, `drupal_get_path($type, $name)` is the best way to get the path to modules or themes..

Comment: Thaks for your time..!